# Use Angular with Laravel

Tags: laravel, angular, frontend, backend

Anyone know if the best aproach to use laravel and angular is to use angular as Front-End and laravel as back end , or can i use both of them in all in One ?

In the case of each option can you explain please why is that the best aproach ?

Thanks Guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to create a RESTFUL api in laravel as the backend, and use angular as the font-end client. This is currently the most popular approach as angular is great for creating what are known as "Single Page Applications" (SPA's). SPA's are popular because they allow you to create a seamless user experience by appropriately handling asynchronous behaviour. By keeping your REST api separate from your UI, you can also then add other clients as needed, such as a mobile/native client.

Comment: I don't know why this got down voted, this is what I am currently doing, and having done the research beforehand, as well as my experiences while doing it, this is absolutely the best way to do it.

Comment: Neither do i ! but actually appreciate your answer